# Kivy popup size relative to content

Tags: popup, kivy

I am trying to set the height of a popup in kivy so that it varies to fit its content. However, I cannot use `height: self.minimum_height`, as Popup has no attribute minimum_height.

I have also tried setting the height of the popup equal to the height of the content, but the result is far from ideal (and especially wouldn't be consistent across different screen sizes).

This is my code:

```
#:set row_height '35sp'
<ConfirmPopup@Popup>:
    box: box
    message: message
    noButton: noButton
    yesButton: yesButton

    size_hint: .8, None
    height: box.height + sp(80)
    auto_dismiss: False
    StackLayout:
        id: box
        orientation: 'lr-tb'
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        padding: main_padding
        Label:
            id: message
            text: "" # This text is updated later from the py script
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: None, None
            width: self.parent.width
            height: self.texture_size[1]
        Label: # just empty space
            size_hint: .15, None
        Button:
            id: noButton
            size_hint: .3, None
            height: row_height
        Label:
            size_hint: .1, None
        Button:
            id: yesButton
            size_hint: .3, None
            height: row_height
        Label:
            size_hint: .15, None
```

Comment: Can you use `BoxLayout` instead of `StackLayout`? The `BoxLayout` does have `minimum_height`.

Comment: You mean the problem is with the StackLayout? I think the issue is rather with the Popup not having a minimum_height property. The height of my stack layout is as I want it to be (label height + buttons height, which are fixed). It is the popup that does not adjust to the height of the StackLayout.

Comment: any other ideas on this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you want to see and what are you seeing?